# Opening Windows Explorer XP - launches another program

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

Every time I try to launch Windows Explorer in Windows XP, Windows tries to launch an installation procedure from some software that has been on my system for a long time. (Mindjet Manager 6)

`IDriver.exe` and `IdrverT.exe` are the associated processes shown in the task manager.

Once I cancel the installation procedure Windows Explorer launches as normal.

Can anyone tell me how to fix the issue please?

I think this problem has resulted from running Norton 360's registry cleanup program.

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to try the Microsoft Installation Cleaanup Utility.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2438651

It sounds like Mindjet associated integrated itself with Explorer, and since not uninstalled properly, and the installation files not removed, it is working in an advertised state.  This means on first use, it tries to install the program.